# What are color conversion codes ending in FULL for?

Tags: opencv3.0

Several [color conversion codes](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0a2dd48d4bc63904a55500a4ef5608f7e1) in OpenCV 3.2 have two versions, one ending in _FULL, and one not, e.g.:

```
  cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL = 66,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL = 67,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2HLS_FULL = 68,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2HLS_FULL = 69,
  cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR_FULL = 70,
  cv::COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL = 71,
  cv::COLOR_HLS2BGR_FULL = 72,
  cv::COLOR_HLS2RGB_FULL = 73,
```

What is the difference between the two? I couldn't find it in the documentation. Specifically, when I use a color conversion code like in:

```
converted_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I tried converting them using HSV and HSV_FULL and they have the exact same properties. The difference could be HSV_FULL isn't backward compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result will be different in H dimension.

According to my observation, the options with "_FULL" suffix has a larger H range than the ones without it. What's more, the L and S dimension should be the same.

Answer (score 4):

The hue range in Open CV is [0,179], the saturation and intensity range from [0,255], as per [Official Docs](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html). So one has to normalise the hue to the range [0,255]. The options with "_FULL" have the hue range defined to [0-255].